# ASp.Net MVC 2 Performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

What is the **latest** data on ASP.Net MVC performance? How does it scale and perform under heavy load?

I have profiled my ASP.Net MVC 1 application and most of the time is wasted in System.Web.MVC assembly, so I thought it might be a concern.

Comment: So Runs on MVC 1, seems to fair well :)  If you're having performance trouble in MVC 1: your might be more concerned with how your current code is using it rather than the framework itself, it's **very** lightweight.

Comment: My code is more lightweight than MVC. MVC uses more time than nHibernate, that's why I'm conserned.

Comment: How are you measuring this, based strictly on time percentage?  If I fire up a for loop and call an MVC function (even the lightest function of almost anything is more expensive than a `for`) a few thousand times, percentage wise it looks like the framework is a hog...but that's not true, it's the **use of** the framework that results in the time spent % being skewed.  Without knowing how you're measuring it's hard to tell, but MVC being heavier than nHibernate (with more than 1 or 2 queries, e.g. actually doing work) has *never* been a case I've seen.

Comment: I assume you are talking about LINQ2SQL vs. nHibernate. Because that comparison would make more sense to me...

Comment: How are you profiling it?  Elapsed time or cpu time?  What profiler?

Comment: @HeavyWave: If you'd understand the inner workings of Asp.net WebForms and compare it against MVC then you'd just put your hat down to MVC. It's so lightweight it should be known by its second name **Asp.net Hælium**

Answer (score 6):

"MVC uses more time than nHibernate"

This can't be true.

Even with a simple select with nHibernate your probably looking at more than 50ms for connection, query translation, query execution, and finally materialization against MSSQL.

A base MVC request against with no logic returns in < 1 ms.

Comment: +1 I support this, according to my experience with MVC and NHibernate, I have never encountered a situation where MVC code is slower than NHibernate.

@Heavy Wave: May be some thing more serious is going on in your MVC code!

Comment: Yeah, MVC methods were waiting for nHibernate, that's what was going on. Still would be nice to see some data on MVCs performance.

Answer (score 1):

In fact this site (stack overflow) is done in asp.net MVC 1. How does it seem speed wise?

Answer (score 0):

We have a high traffic ASP.NET MVC website and it performs well.

Dont worry about the time spent in MVC itself. This will not be an issue.

The main issue I see for even more traffic on our site is that we can only cache complete Actions. But right now this all looks better then expected.